# Force case-sensitive routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

This question has been asked in a similar but not identical fashion (and not resolved to my satisfaction) [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170900/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-content-in-asp-net-mvc-due-to-case-insensitive-urls-an) and [elsewhere](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/lowercase-urls-with-aspnet-mvc).

Coming from a linux-world, I want to use ASP.NET MVC but avoid identical but differently-cased routes from resolving to the same page. I do *not* want to force all routes to be 100% lowercase.

e.g. I want `/Home/Something` to be a valid route and `/Home/somethingElse` to also be a valid route, but not `/Home/something` or `/home/somethingelse`, given two functions called `Something` and `somethingElse` in the `HomeController`.

I can't find any way of doing this from within the `RegisterRoutes` function, but maybe I'm missing something obvious? I can answer this easily enough by adding code to each Controller function, but I'm obviously trying to avoid doing that.

Optimally, the solution would involve catching *all* permutations of a particular route, then 301 redirecting any that do not exactly match the case of the controller's function.

Comment: MVC and ASP.NET Webforms can both use the same routing engine.

Comment: It's worth noting that you haven't indicated C# or VB.Net - VB.Net is inherently case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find *any* way of doing this after extensive searching. Basically, case-sensitivity and IIS/ASP.NET apparently do not go together.

We're now using a bit of a kludge to solve this. The code has been opensourced (MIT license) on github: [NeoSmart Web Toolkit](https://github.com/NeoSmart/web), in particular, [this file containing the SEO redirect code](https://github.com/NeoSmart/web/blob/master/Web%20Toolkit/Seo.cs).

Using it is easy enough: each GET method in the controller classes needs to add just this one line at the start:

```
Seo.SeoRedirect(this);
```

The SEO rewrite class automatically uses C# 5.0's Caller Info attributes to do the heavy lifting, making the code above strictly copy-and-paste.

Ideally, I would love to find a way to turn that line of code into an attribute. For instance, prefixing the controller methods with `[CaseSensitive]` would automatically have the same effect as writing in that line, but alas, I do not (yet) know how to do this.

I also can't find any way of figuring this out with the `Routing` class/structures. That's some opaque code!