# How to create Uri from input string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the string 
    "https://www.AbcXyz.org/schema/Attributes#"
I want to convert it to Uri. The line of code is

```
public static Uri Create(String uri){
        Uri u = new Uri(uri);
        node.Value = u;

        return new Uri(uri);
    }
```

But this code is returning 
    "https://www.abcxyz.org/schema/Attributes#"

How can I get the exact string I passed? Can we have Uppercase letters in URI?
because I need to use that URI in a graph database to store as triple data as a database is a case-sensitive

Comment: Since the difference is only by the case of host name, it may considered equal according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746053/c-sharp-how-to-use-uri-equal. Only the paths and query strings are treated case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But what if I want my hostname should be same as the one which I provided. Can we do that thing here? If Yes, How?

Comment: Looking at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs it doesn't seem there is a way to get your original string back. You'll have to do something else like use an `out` for your original string or use a tuple return type to return the new `Uri` and the original string.

Answer (score 2):

The [Uri.OriginalString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.originalstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) property will return the original string passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

- In case of using Uri check the Remarks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7.2
- Mind if you don't use it anyway if you want only to import it to the db.