# Controller requires lowercase in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I added a new Controller called "ListController" in to MVC project

if I write in browser Url `http://localhost:1509/list` everything works fine

But if I write in browser Url `"http://localhost:1509/List"` I get Erorr page

The only difference is if the letter L in the URL is capitalized or lowercase letter

What causes it

Comment: What does your routes look like? If you put a breakpoint at the relevant action, does it get hit, or does it fail prior to the action?

Comment: It works either case, i think no case sensitivity

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170900/how-can-i-avoid-duplicate-content-in-asp-net-mvc-due-to-case-insensitive-urls-an

Comment: the action isn't be hit in case of List!

Comment: I have a lot Controllers in project and all it does work well

Answer (score 0):

Either case sensitive routing has been configured in the global.asax file without you knowing about it, or you are missing something.

Asp.net mvc routing urls are not case sensitive by default. "home", "HOME", "hOmE", etc.. are all the exact same as far as the mvc routing engine is concerned.

Here is the url where ScottGu explains the Asp.Net MVC url Routing Rules how they work.

[ScottGu - ASP.Net MVC Framework: URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: Thank you There was a problem truly